# How to limit download traffic in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

Is there a setting in Firefox to limit the download traffic speed? For example, I want to download some files using Firefox with *max.* 200 *kbps* whereas I want to use the remaining limit to download some other files with a torrent client.

Note: I don't like to use an external download manager. I'd prefer a Firefox add-on instead.

Comment: The question probably needs some OS tags if you want to do this on the computer that runs Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

[Downthemall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) has a per-server speed limit which you can configure under Network Preferences. Wildcards (*) for a global limit don't seem to work though.

[image: Network Preferences]

Comment: It would be great if DTA worked for a global limit. It does not solve the problem as it is.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar DownThemAll *does* have a global limit. It's on the bottom right of the main "Manager" window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com). It is a shareware tool where you can adjust how applications use your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

FireFox throttle may work (ffthrottle.xpi). Though it's not being updated and was removed from addons site so you have to find it on ftps out there.

Also you can find free alternatives to [NetLimiter](http://alternativeto.net/software/netlimiter/?license=free) and add your tips too!

NetBalancer seems a good option! it has limitations for unregistered users but probably is enough for most users!