# Limiting download speed in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to limit download traffic in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/56914/how-to-limit-download-traffic-in-firefox) 
>   [Throttling Bandwidth on Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/297272/throttling-bandwidth-on-firefox) 
>   [Simulate limited bandwidth from within Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox)

How do I limit download speeds in Firefox? For example, limit the maximum download speed to 100 KB/s?

I use Firefox 11 portable, Windows 7 Home x64.

Comment: Maybe because it does not meet the [quality standards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075)... being too short is a common cause.

Comment: It's so nice having a [search](http://superuser.com/search)... [Throttling Bandwidth on Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/297272/throttling-bandwidth-on-firefox) [How to limit download traffic in Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/56914/how-to-limit-download-traffic-in-firefox) [Simulate limited bandwidth from within Firefox?](http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox) The top one is most recent, therefore most up to date.

Comment: I removed the second part of your question. Questions about the site Super User itself belongs on [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/)

Comment: @Nifle I use Firefox 11 portable, I downloaded Throttle, it seems that its old and firefox say its not compatible with current version.

Comment: @XinHua Then please indicate that when you ask your question. Show *all* your research so we can avoid providing redundant information. Fishing for information is not fun. Also, see the first question I linked to, that one's more recent (i.e. after Throttle was no longer relevant).

Comment: @Bob I saw all three links, no one is useful

Comment: @XinHua In what way was `NetLimiter` (as suggested in the answers to all three questions) not useful? How does it not suit your requirements? Please be specific. Does the program/method need to be portable? Then *say so*. I can guess from the fact that you're using a portable copy of Firefox, but **I don't want to guess**. **Tell me**. As your question stands, NetLimiter is a viable solution (it can limit speeds to Firefox, which is your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is using NetLimiter.

Here's [a video on how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FZpVBV5uw4).

In summary:

- Download [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) (freeware and paid option are both available)
- Install the software.
- Choose the programs you wish to limit download speed for.

Comment: Done thanks. Should have done that without thinking.

Comment: Thanks! I added a little formatting (make sure to check our tools for that) and removed salutations and irrelevant stuff from your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: gotcha, exactly how it should be. Really nice to be taught a way to be good at using the mighty stack. I will look forward to answering more questions.